# Using JPA Criteria API to fetch a list

Tags: java, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I have an entity `Tutor` with two relationships in class `Schedule`. Code below defines the relationship between the two entities.

```
public class Tutor{
   //list of schedules created by tutor
   @OneToMany
   List<Schedule> schedules;
 }
```

then

```
public class Schedule{

    //tutor who created this schedule
    @ManyToOne
    Tutor tutor;

    //tutors who would be examiners of this schedule
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable
    List<Tutor> examiners;
   }
```

how can i query `Tutor` and fetch all `Schedule(s)` where `Tutor` is an `examiner` using criteria api

Comment: What if the tutor examines a schedule he didn't create? That would not show in your current setup. You should rather query the `Schedule` table where the tutor is an examiner

Comment: I have been contemplating that for a while, in my use case the tutor who creates a schedule might not necessarily be an examiner even though the said tutor created the schedule. From your comment, i should look to query the schedule table rather than traversing the relationships from `Tutor`.

Comment: There are 2 possible approaches, though one will possibly be missing `Schedules`. 1st: query tutor with all the schedules he created and remove the schedules for which he is not an examiner (you might be missing the ones he does examine but didn't create). 2nd: query the mapping table to get all schedules where the tutor is an examiner. This would get you all schedules which the tutor examines. However, this is harder to do with criteria api. With criteria you will start at `Schedule` and need to find the ones where the tutor is a part of examiners. A native query would probably be easier tho